# Change Window 10 installation language

Tags: windows-10, installation, language, windows-installation

A few years ago I made a clean installation of Windows 10 with a non-English interface language. After installation I changed the GUI language to English by applying a language pack.

Since then, every major system update (like "anniversary" or "creators") has reset this language to initial one (which is the language of installation source). How can I change the language for sure to avoid installing language packs in future? Please, don't advise to change something in control panel or settings - it's already English and system GUI language is also English for current account and default accounts.

Comment: You cannot. It requires installing windows with the right language to begin with. Every major update basically resets windows to some degree.

Comment: @LPChip I thought this language value should be in registry or somewhere else within the OS, isn't it?

Comment: You have already done what you need to do.  @LPChip is correct, the reason it is setting itself to the language of the installation, is because your downloading the feature update for the language not the language your switching too.

Comment: @Ramhound that "feature update" was downloaded by the system itself, so I was expecting feature language to be equal to current GUI language. But it's not...

Comment: In theory what you would do is download the English 1703 ISO instead of the language ISO of the original ISO you used to install Windows.  I wouldn't trust doing that on a production system though.

Comment: @AlekDepler - That is because while you changed the language, the installation language, is still whatever it is.